# flashing current point on line chart using AchartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

Hello i am using AchartEngine to draw a line chart . it draws the chart on run time getting value from Bluetooth device all works fine but problem is that how could i put a drawable image to show the current position as we show on map. Any help or suggestions would be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean make a custom graph point that's not a circle, square, or triangle?

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to put a small image on current position.